# how do i organise this function so it works as i intend it to

Tags: java, android, loops

im new to android studio and i want this function to loop and create an infinite ball falling loop which will be scored until the two integers do not match but when i try to run it, it will only loop once and if i change `streak = 2` in the `else` statement the app crashes

```
public void mainGameLoop(){
    do {
        //sets Balls integer
        setColourint();
        ball.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //ball fall
        float bottomOfScreen = getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
                .heightPixels - (ball.getHeight() * 4);

        //fall animation
        ball.animate()
                .translationY(bottomOfScreen)
                .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                .setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator())
                .setDuration(9000);
        //once animation is complete compares balls variable with current variable
        if (colourint == ranint){
            //if they are same then +1 score
            score = score+1;
            scr.setText(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(score)));

        } else {
            //else game is over
             streak = 2;
        }
        //repeat until game is over
    } while (streak == 1);
}
```

once the balls reached the bottom of the relative layout i want the function to check if the `setcoulour int` and the `ran int` are the same and then if the are         `score = score + 1`, ball goes back to the top, the `setColourInt` function is called and the ball falls again(and so on and so on) but if not loop ends and it's game over...i apologise for my blatant incompetence but I can't imagine you guys don't remember when you too, were this naive when it came to coding. many thanks Tom

Comment: What is it doing now that you consider "wrong?"

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the UI a chance to draw what you're doing. The way you have it coded, whichever method (`onStart`, `onCreate`, etc) that calls your `mainGameLoop` will never return because it's stuck in an infinite loop. This is an error.

One way to do this is to create a `View` and implement your game draw logic in the `onDraw` method. The UI thread will call your `onDraw` method when it is time to draw. Here's an article that talks about this approach: http://cjds.github.io/2014/04/28/Creating-a-simple-android-game/